# Flask - Pass argument to URL - 405 Error

Tags: python, redirect, flask, http-status-code-405

I am learning Flask and I am having some trouble passing arguments to a URL for use on another page. For example, I have a form on `/index` and I would like it to redirect to a `/results` page where I could print the form data. My attempt is this:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for

from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.artistName.data
        return redirect(url_for('result', name=name))
    else:
        return redirect('/index')
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form)

@app.route('/result/<name>')
def result(name):
    return render_template('results.html')
```

I receive a 405 error `Method not allowed for the requested URL` when redirecting to the `/results` page. I would like to construct a URL on `/results` using the result of the form as an argument.

How can I do this? Many thanks

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the error that you're facing ?

Comment: Please, post the error traceback message.

Comment: I receive a 405 error `Method not allowed for the requested URL` when redirecting to the `/results` page.

Answer (score 0):

you defined

```
@app.route('/result/<name>')
```

which means its default http method is `GET`；
when this runs:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    # POST method
    name = form.artistName.data
    # redirect Will use 'POST'
    return redirect(url_for('result', name=name))
```

so ,  you got `Method not allowed for the requested URL`.

i think you can add a `POST` method to `@app.route('/result/<name>')`

Comment: Adding a `POST` method to `@app.route('/result/<name>')` results in a redirect loop, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Yes, it does redirect to login. In fact, only Get method is allowed to redirect directly. I think this can help:

    @app.route('/result/<name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])